# Gather countdown timer with jsoup and setup a timer for android

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I want to parse a countdown timer from ebay

```
<span id="vi-cdown_timeLeft" class="">5g 20h </span>
```

How can I parse it with jsoup to create a countdown timer on android studio?

Can I parse it like a normal `element`? Like below

Update:
the getMsFromString is the same method written by below from shn android dev

```
public synchronized void getTimer() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sem.acquire();

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(linkurl).get();
                remaining = doc.select("#vi-cdown_timeLeft").first().text();
                msFromString = getMsFromString(remaining);
                long remainingMs = System.currentTimeMillis() - msFromString;
                new CountDownTimer(remainingMs, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        timer.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        timer.setText("done!");
                    }

                }.start();
                sem.release();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried it? If so, what happened?

Comment: updated the main post :D

Comment: did any answer solve your problem? If so, please accept the appropriate answer and by that marking the question as solved for others. If you found an answer useful, don't hesitate to upvote for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the HTML part of the ebay webpage associated with the countdown timer looks like this:

```
<span class="vi-tm-left">
     <span class="timeMs" timems="1522415936000">Friday, 8:18AM</span>
</span>
```

You want to get the value of the `span` *element* with the "timems" *attribute*. Note, that `timems` is the number of milliseconds elapsed since Jan 01, 1970.

In your JSoup try executing the following code to get the value of `timems` (you need to change the URL to where your eBay bid is located!):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://myebayurl.com/").get();
Element timeSpanEle = doc.select("span.timeMs").first();
long timeMs = Long.parseLong(timeSpanEle.attr("timems"));
```

Now we have the value of the Unix timestamp (in milliseconds, not seconds!) indicating when the auction expires. Now we need to make a countdown timer on Android Studio. We can use the `android.os.CountDownTimer` to do this, since you haven't specified a class you'd like to use (however this should give you an idea how to do it).

```
long remainingMs = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeMs;
new CountDownTimer(remainingMs, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }

}.start();
```

EDIT: So the content in the original post has changed a little bit. The HTML with the time remaining for the auction is not a UNIX timestamp according to you but a String value, and thus the previous answer will not work for you. This is because the Italian version of the Ebay website (the one OP is using) is different from the American one (the version I erroneously assumed OP was using). Here is an updated answer.

Given that the time you're dealing with is in the following format and not a UNIX timestamp:

> Xg Yh Zm

Where X is the number of days (g), Y is the number of hours (h) and Z is the number of minutes (m).

We get the value of the time remaining by the following:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://myebayurl.com/").get();
String remaining = doc.select("#vi-cdown_timeLeft").first().text();
```

We now need to parse this String and convert it into ms remaining. Take the time remaining String from above and parse it into ms with the following static method:

```
public static long getMsFromString(String str) {
    String[] arr = str.split(" ");
    long auctionTimeLeft = 0;
    for(String s : arr){
        if(s.contains("g")) { //convert days to milliseconds
            auctionTimeLeft += Long.parseLong(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("g"))) * 8.64e7;
        }
        else if(s.contains("h")){ //convert hours to milliseconds
            auctionTimeLeft += Long.parseLong(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("h"))) * 3.6e6;
        }
        else if(s.contains("m")){ //convert minutes to milliseconds
            auctionTimeLeft += Long.parseLong(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("m"))) * 60000;
        }
    }
    return auctionTimeLeft;
}
```

**Conclusion**

1. Get the auction time remaining string from ebay (i.e. "3g 10h 5m")
2. Call `getMsFromString` on the string from first step
3. Use the milliseconds remaining in step 2 in the count down timer (remainingMs in the example above)

Comment: Hey, thanks for help :) on ebay i can only find <span id="vi-cdown_timeLeft" class="">3g 22h </span> for get the timer, not timeMs..

Comment: @DanieleAsta Interesting... What does the "g" in 3g 22h mean? I guess if your HTML is appearing differently what you can do is get 3g 22h as a string from the HTML using attr() method then translating the string into days, hours and mins for your Android timer. Ill post an edit to this in a bit if you need help

Comment: Oh Sorry, in Italy g stand for Day so its like: 3d 22h,i edited the main post, could u check it?

Comment: Thanks again for the help, i updated the code but i can't still figure out how make it work, looks llike it doesnt set it on the TextView, i update the main post with new method code.

Comment: @DanieleAsta You cannot update the UI from a different thread. Since you're trying to change the text value of your TextView in a thread not on the UI, you're encountering a problem. See https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html on how to do this, or try modifying your code to use AsyncTask

Comment: Hi, i updated.. sadly i still get an error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.jsoup.nodes.Element.text()' on a null object reference... looks like  doc.select("#vi-cdown_timeLeft").first().text(); can't parse the timer.

Comment: @DanieleAsta Is the Document object JSoup is creating from the url you're passing it still valid and has an element with id=#vi-cdown_timeLeft?

Comment: yes, <span id="vi-cdown_timeLeft" class="">4g 21h </span> the url is valid because i also use it for parse the image and title, and it works fine, the only problem is gathering the timer

Comment: Can you give me the ebay URL you are using? I want to see what its doing

Comment: sure https://www.ebay.it/itm/ASTE-A-PARTENZA-ZERO-COLONIE-LIBIA-SERIE-PITTORICA-tracce-linguella/123057166318?hash=item1ca6c757ee:g:5xgAAOSwOtVaw7TP, it's the italian ebay

Comment: @DanieleAsta I just tried the code with the website you gave me and it works. Look over the code and make sure you understand what is doing! There is also some math involved so make sure you have applied it correctly in your code!

Comment: could u post me on pastebin the full code? i want to compair it with mine :) thanks

Comment: @DanieleAsta Sure. Let me know if it works for you. Here ya go: https://pastebin.com/ByPFcWfQ

Comment: Hey @Shn_Android_Dev i tried to implement ur code to my project, thanks for help.. i'll get this error now.. NetworkOnMainThreadException. i'll post my code (sorry if it is ugly, but im a beginner :P) https://pastebin.com/EEa5R9hm

Comment: P.S your code works well for me, but i can't get how to implement it on android.. thanks for help :D

Comment: @DanieleAsta The error message means you cannot use HTTP requests on the main thread; i.e. you have to run the code in the pastebin on a separate thread. Use the AsyncTask class and run the code in the background method. I'd recommend asking a new question if you're going to delve into that.