# Jsoup HTML Parsing work on java but doesn't work on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jsoup

im working on a html parsing project using Jsoup, im able to parse Title and Image correctly, but when i try to parse a timer (related to this post [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565617/gather-countdown-timer-with-jsoup-and-setup-a-timer-for-android/)) i fail on android studio but works with the code gave me for java by @Shn_Android_Dev  [This Code](https://pastebin.com/ByPFcWfQ),
 and this is my code..

```
public void EbayTimerTest() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(WEBSITE_URL).get();
                String remaining = doc.select("#vi-cdown_timeLeft").first().text();
                remainingMs = getUnixFromString(remaining);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timer.setText(String.valueOf(remainingMs));
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
    }
}
```

and the error i still get is

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.jsoup.nodes.Element.text()' on a null object reference`

pretty sure the

```
String remaining = doc.select("#vi-cdown_timeLeft").first().text();
```

fail to parse on android studio but works on Java Eclipse..

p.s Jsoup works well if i try to parse others Element such Title and Image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for the exception may be that each IDE sends a different `userAgent` string to the server, so you get two different HTMLs.
You can solve it in one of two ways:

1. Read the `doc` you get with AS and see what is the query for the information that you need.
2. Add the `userAgent` string to the `get` request -

   ```
   doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101")
   .get();
   ```